# tentando deletar documento do firestore, erro de crash, reinicia app e não da nem mensagem de erro no debuger

Tags: android, firestore

Estou tentando deletar um documento, no entanto o *app* simplesmente fecha sozinho. Já tentei tudo que sei, mas o erro persiste. Não entendo o porquê. O código em si está correto.

O caminho geral é esse:

> /tutores/zqfcZEX1E4UFEEaVcocR/pets

Alguém já viu erro similar?

```
dbFirestore.collection("/tutores").document(mTutorID).collection("/pets").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (int i = 0; i<queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().size(); i++){
                        String fotonome = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(i).get("foto_nome").toString();
                        StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
                        StorageReference  petRefFoto = storageRef.child("pets/"+fotonome);
                        petRefFoto.delete();
                        queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(i).getReference().delete();
                    }

                    StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
                    StorageReference  tutorRefFoto = storageRef.child("tutores/"+mTutorFotoNome);
                    tutorRefFoto.delete();

                    dbFirestore.collection("/tutores").document(mTutorID).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {                            AbreLogin();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ocorreu algum problema, NÃO foi possivel apagar as contas dos pets, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

O erro acontece quando este documento raiz é deletado:

```
dbFirestore.collection("/tutores").document(mTutorID).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            AbreLogin();
                        }
                    });
```

O caminho geral é esse

> /tutores/zqfcZEX1E4UFEEaVcocR/pets

Comment: Qual registro do *log* no Android Studio?

Comment: ele nao dá mensagem de erro, ele apaga o documento, fecha a activity e mesmo sem nenhum comando que fala ele voltar a activity anterior que tem um get com addSnapshotListener() ele obviamente da erro por nao ter mais o documento....pq ele ainda faz leitura em um get com addSnapshotListener() de activity que nao esta mais mostrando? o que devo fazer???

Answer (score 0):

descobri  que é so remover os SnapshotListener registrando eles da seguinte maneira:
crio a variavel para guarda-los

```
ListenerRegistration registration;

registration = dbFirestore.collection("/tutores").whereEqualTo("email", TutorEmail ).addSnapshotListener()...
```

e depois removo eles quando necessário:

```
if (registration!= null) {
    registration.remove();
    registration = null;
}
```

Comment: em pensar que perdi dois dias, so repetindo a mesma coisa, erro no codigo eu sabia que nao tinha, faltava era descobrir um erro na logica ne, rss